# Style background not showing an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I can't seem to solve this, The URLs are not showing as images, what can I do?

I think the issue is with the style background image but I'm not sure, the name is showing fine but the image is not.

here is the code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import TinderCard from "react-tinder-card";


function TinderCards() {

const [people, setPeople] = useState([
    {
        name:"sonny", 
        url:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Lola_Astanova.jpg",
    },
    {
        name:"danny",
        url:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Lola_Astanova.jpg",
    },
]);
// const people = [];             array
return (
    <div>
      <h1>cards</h1>

             {people.map((person) => ( <TinderCard 
             className="swipe"
             key={person.name}
             preventSwipe={['up', 'down']}
             >



                 
                 <div 
                     // eslint-disable-next-line no-template-curly-in-string
                     style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(${person.url})' }}
                     className="card">
                     <h3>{person.name}</h3>
                     
                 </div>
             </TinderCard>
             ))}
    </div>
);
 }

 export default TinderCards
```

Comment: try changing to backticks: ``style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${person.url})` }}``

Comment: yes, try hard code the image url first and see if it works, and then try the above suggestion :)

Comment: @sava128 Love you, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's what I would do as well. Work backwards if stuck. I would think the tics would work. Not showing image equates to? Have you viewed source / what was output?